kivy invalid class name error while using builder method
i am making the real time app using kivy but i am having problem, i am following a tutorial and merge its two tutorials. Now i am having error "invalid class name".
now i need help that i want to make the app who can show real time data, but need the interface to it where i add buttons in it, and switch between it. each pages shows the data of patients.
in this the navigation bar is at the top and down that i want to swipe pages with button.
the error is:


54:    :
55:        name:'patient1'
56:        MDRectangleFlatButton:
...
Invalid class name


from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivymd.uix.label import MDLabel
from kivymd.uix.screen import Screen
from kivymd.uix.button import MDFlatButton, MDRectangleFlatButton, MDIconButton, MDFloatingActionButton
from kivymd.uix.dialog import MDDialog
from kivymd.uix.textfield import MDTextField
from kivymd.uix.list import MDList, OneLineListItem, TwoLineListItem, ThreeLineListItem
from kivymd.uix.list import IconLeftWidget, TwoLineIconListItem
from kivy.uix.scrollview import ScrollView
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import Screen, ScreenManager
from kivymd.uix.datatables import MDDataTable
from kivy.metrics import dp
from kivy.core.window import Window

# from kivymd.uix.toolbar import MDTopAppBar

Window.size = (300, 500)

screen_helper = """
Screen:
    MDNavigationLayout:
        ScreenManager:
            Screen:
                MDBoxLayout:
                    orientation:'vertical'
                    MDTopAppBar:
                        title: 'Healthcare Application'
                        left_action_items: [["menu",lambda x: nav_drawer.set_state('toggle')]]
                        elevation: 2

                    Widget:

            PatientOne:
            PatientTwo:
 
                    # MDBottomAppBar:
                    #     MDTopAppBar:
                    #         title: 'Title'
                    #         icon: 'git'
                    #         type: 'bottom'
                    #         mode: 'end'
                    #         on_action_button: app.navigation_draw()
                    #         left_action_items: [["menu", lambda x: x]]
        MDNavigationDrawer:
            id: nav_drawer
            BoxLayout:
                orientation: 'vertical'
                spacing: '8dp'
                padding: '8dp'
                MDLabel:
                    text: 'Tehseen Baig'
                    font_style: 'Subtitle1'
                    size_hint_y: None
                    height: self.texture_size[1]
                MDLabel:
                    text: 't3hseen'
                    font_style: 'Caption'
                    size_hint_y: None
                    height: self.texture_size[1]

                ScrollView:
                    MDList:
                        OneLineIconListItem:
                            text: 'Item1'
                            IconLeftWidget:
                                icon: 'android'
                        OneLineIconListItem:
                            text: 'Item2'
                            IconLeftWidget:
                                icon: 'android'
           
    <PatientOne>:
        name:'patient1'
        MDRectangleFlatButton:
            text:'Profile'
            pos_hint: {'center_x':0.5,'center_y':0.5}
            on_press: root.manager.current = 'patient2'
    
    <PatientTwo>:
        name:'patient2'
        MDRectangleFlatButton:
            text:'Profile2'
            pos_hint: {'center_x':0.5,'center_y':0.5}
            on_press: root.manager.current = 'patient1'         

"""


class PatientOne(Screen):
    pass


class PatientTwo(Screen):
    pass


sm = ScreenManager()
sm.add_widget(PatientOne(name='patient1'))
sm.add_widget(PatientTwo(name='patient2'))


class healthcareApp(MDApp):

    def build(self):
        self.theme_cls.primary_palette = 'Red'
        self.theme_cls.material_style = "M2"
        screen = Builder.load_string(screen_helper)
        return screen

    def navigation_draw(self):
        print("Navigation")


healthcareApp().run()



You probably need to add an import to your screen_helper. See the documentation.
